# Drupal View 's path. how to make drupal view's node link back to view's page rather than node type

Tags: drupal, view, path

I created a node type, say 'Project' with the path as '**/pro/{node:title}**', and then I created a 'Project view', in this view I show the project information as well as some other information by using the **attachments** and **relationships**. The path of view is /project/%, argument is project 's title

in order to avoid the conflict, so you see 'Project' node type is '**/pro/{node:title}**', 
                                           'Project' view type is  **/project/%**

For this view, I created a page and a block, the problem is in the block, I want to make block's title link to the view 's page rather than node 's page. so that means, when in the view block, there is a link for the project, when I click this link, it will bring me to the 'project' 's view( project/% ) instead of  'project' node type(pro/{node:tile}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my problem solved. 
by working with view, I can use the option 'rewrite the output of this field' to add the link to the view instead of node type